# Cumulant-Legendre

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convex-analysis

I have a short question:
So suppose $b=\text{ess sup} X<\infty$, where $X$ is a random variable on $\mathbb{R}$. Now take $\Lambda (u)=\ln \mathbb{E}[e^{uX}]$, the cumulant, and $\Lambda^*(x)=\sup_u\{ux-\Lambda (u)\}$. We can assume that $\Lambda$ is smooth. Now, in a proof (of Cramer's theorem) I found the following statement:
$$-\Lambda^*(b)=\ln P(X=b)$$
It should be easy to proof, but somehow I can't show it. Could you help me :) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

would that work:
$$
e^{-\Lambda(b)}=e^{\inf_u\Lambda (u)-ub}=\inf_u e^{\Lambda (u)-ub}=\inf_u \mathbb{E}[e^{u(X-b)},X<b]+P(X=b)=P(X=b)
$$